# INSERT Tomorrow's date + Hour in a DATETIME field

Tags: mysql

I would like to insert in a datetime field the date of tomorrow + **07:00:00** to have a valid datetime value.

I've tried with

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES(CURDATE()+1)
```

but it just inserts me tomorrow's date and 00:00:00 time:

```
2012-01-19 00:00:00
```

How can I insert it with the specified time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add 1 day to CURDATE() and then add 7 hours to that result:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES (TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, 7, TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 1, CURDATE())))
```

Comment: Or you could go for `INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL '1 7' DAY_HOUR));` to make it a bit cleaner

Comment: @WillSneddon, that works too. I am not sure @ianenri wants to add 7 hours to same time next day, which is why I went with `CURDATE` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Besides that, your syntax is cleaner than mine. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Just to be clear, i wanted to have "07:00:00 time" of the next day more than just adding 7 hours.

Answer (score 4):

you need:

```
INSERT INTO sometable VALUES (DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)

Comment: Just remembered this and edited my answer, but you beat me to it.

Comment: It just inserts me the date but 00:00:00 time, and i want 07:00:00

Comment: Is the column data type TIMESTAMP or DATETIME ? Just double checked on a database, that inserts the date + 1 day and the current time it was executed.

Comment: Checked again, this does insert the time of execution [relative to the SQL server] into the field. You mentioned you want '+ 07:00:00' is that a fixed time or an additional 7 hours on to the timestamp ? or a fixed '07:00:00' on to tomorrows date ?

Comment: @WillSneddon Fixed '07:00:00' on tomorrow's date.

Answer (score 0):

In that case how about `CURDATE() + 1 + CURTIME()`.

EDIT: Actually, use the `DATE_ADD` function:

`DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)`